# Views... two panes each contains a view.  One is the exposed filter, other is the fields.  How can they communicate?

Tags: 7, views, panels

I have have two panes each containing a view.  But, these views are and exposed filter and it's fields/results.  How can I make these views aware of each other?  I want results of the exposed filtered view to be displayed in the other fields pane.

I'm assuming this would be done through relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Exposed filters are only linked to the view they were exposed on.

I haven't done this before, but I think the correct method would be:

1. Create a view
2. Expose any of the filters you need to on that view (not a separate one)
3. In the advanced settings of that view, set "Exposed form in block" to yes
4. Add the block to your panel (not a separate views pane)

Comment: I want them to be in separate panes so the results can be outputted horizontally to the exposed filters instead of below.  I'm wondering if I could use relationships to achieve this.

Comment: You can add the exposed block in a separate pane than the view in panels to get that result. When adding content to your pane, look under Miscellaneous for the exposed block. It will be called "Exposed form: viewname" IIRC

Answer (score 1):

Use a single View, and expose its filters. Under the exposed filters settings, you can choose to expose them as a block. When doing so, the exposed filters from won't show up above the view's results. Display the view in a pane and it's exposed filters block in another.

Note: Relationships are used to bring data from additional *base tables* (in Views *speech*, not in SQL) related to the main *base table* used for the view. For instance, to bring data from the *user* table related to the main *node* table. Once you have added one, you can filter on a relationship' fields.